# Replace parameter in an action filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, lambda, key-value

I am trying to remove the password captured in the parameters from my action filter and replace it with the word "Removed", in order for the parameters to be stored in the database for logging. The password is stored in a `ViewModel` (depending on the action). Below is sort of a "pseudo-code" as to what I am trying to achieve.

How would I go about masking/replacing the password to be saved in the database? The main issue I am having is that I do not know how to access the password parameter and change it. I have tried getting it using the `actionParams.TryGetValue("model, out value)` but the problem is that I do not know the type of value and it changes depending on the action. Also, I am unable to call many methods on `actionParams["model"]` (such as contains)

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        var actionParam = filterContext.ActionParameters;

        // Remove the password from the parameters
        if (actionParam.ContainsKey("model") && actionParam["model"] != null)
        {           
            // If actionParam["model"].ToLower().Contains("password")
            // actionParam["model"]["password"] = "Removed";

            // If actionParam["model"].ToLower().Contains("confirm password")
            // actionParam["model"]["confirm password"] = "Removed";
        }

        string str = Json.Encode(filterContext.ActionParameters).Trim();

        string par = string.Empty;

        if (str.Length > 2)
        {
            par = str.Substring(1, str.Length - 2).Replace("\"", string.Empty);
        }

        ActionLog log = new ActionLog()
        {
            SessionId = filterContext.HttpContext.Session.SessionID,
            UserName = (request.IsAuthenticated) ? filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name : "Anonymous",
            Controller = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName,
            Action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName,
            ActionParameters = par,
            IsPost = request.HttpMethod.ToLower() == "post" ? true : false,
            IPAddress = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] ?? request.UserHostAddress,
            UserAgent = request.UserAgent,
            ActionDate = filterContext.HttpContext.Timestamp
        };

         //Store the Audit into the Database
        ActionLogContext context = new ActionLogContext();
        context.ActionLogs.Add(log);
        context.SaveChanges();

        // Finishes executing the Action as normal
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    }
```

**Example of possible view models**

```
public class LoginViewModel
{

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User ID")]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", ErrorMessage="Letters and Numbers Only")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
public class ResetPasswordViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

**Example of possible action parameters**

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
```

Comment: Show an example of the view model and the action itself

Comment: This will apply to all actions, so the view model and action will vary

Comment: How are you going to perform login if you're removing the password beforehand?

Comment: @haim770 this will not affect the login. It is being captured so that I could save the parameters (along with other info) into my database for logging/auditing purposes

Comment: @EitanK - Ok, so you want to mask the password in the log. That makes sense. However, if you use this approach the original password won't make it to the action method. You should really put a question in your "article" so people understand what you are asking for and to explain what the problem with your pseudo code is. As it stands, there is no question here to be answered.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I am sorry if the question wasn't so clear. I have modified it so hopefully now it is clearer. If you look at the full code I am saving the `ActionParameters` in a seperate variable but passing back the original, so it shouldn't affect the original password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use an interface as an abstraction so you are not dealing directly with a ViewModel. First, create some interfaces for the action filter to interact with.

```
public interface IPassword
{
    string Password { get; set; }
}

public interface IConfirmPassword
{
    string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Next, make your ViewModel classes implement those interfaces.

```
public class LoginViewModel : IPassword
{

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User ID")]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Letters and Numbers Only")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
public class ResetPasswordViewModel : IPassword, IConfirmPassword
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

Then it is just a matter of updating your filter code. The filter doesn't need to know anything more about your model other than the fact that it implements `IPassword` or `IConfirmPassword`, which it can check with a cast.

Of course, for it to work correctly, you have to restore the original values before executing the action method (or alternatively do the logging after the action is run) so the action method will have the correct values.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var actionParam = filterContext.ActionParameters;
    IPassword password = null;
    IConfirmPassword confirmPassword = null;

    string originalPassword;
    string originalConfirmPassword;

    // Remove the password from the parameters
    if (actionParam.ContainsKey("model") && actionParam["model"] != null)
    {
        // If the model doesn't implement the interface, the result
        // here will be null.
        password = actionParam["model"] as IPassword;
        confirmPassword = actionParam["model"] as IConfirmPassword;
    }

    if (password != null)
    {
        // Store the original value so it can be restored later
        originalPassword = password.Password;
        password.Password = "Removed";
    }

    if (confirmPassword != null)
    {
        // Store the original value so it can be restored later
        originalConfirmPassword = confirmPassword.ConfirmPassword;
        confirmPassword.ConfirmPassword = "Removed";
    }

    string str = Json.Encode(filterContext.ActionParameters).Trim();

    string par = string.Empty;

    if (str.Length > 2)
    {
        par = str.Substring(1, str.Length - 2).Replace("\"", string.Empty);
    }

    ActionLog log = new ActionLog()
    {
        SessionId = filterContext.HttpContext.Session.SessionID,
        UserName = (request.IsAuthenticated) ? filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name : "Anonymous",
        Controller = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName,
        Action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName,
        ActionParameters = par,
        IsPost = request.HttpMethod.ToLower() == "post" ? true : false,
        IPAddress = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] ?? request.UserHostAddress,
        UserAgent = request.UserAgent,
        ActionDate = filterContext.HttpContext.Timestamp
    };

    //Store the Audit into the Database
    ActionLogContext context = new ActionLogContext();
    context.ActionLogs.Add(log);
    context.SaveChanges();

    // Restore the original values
    if (password != null)
    {
        password.Password = originalPassword;
    }

    if (confirmPassword != null)
    {
        confirmPassword.ConfirmPassword = originalConfirmPassword;
    }

    // Finishes executing the Action as normal
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much it works beautifully! Just a quick question, you were right about having to restore the original password, but how come changing the password to "Removed" in my local variable `actionParam` changes the password in `filterContext.ActionParamaters` as well?

Comment: Because classes are reference types. That means when you assign the same class to more than one variable, they are always pointing to the same location in memory. To copy a class, you would have to do a deep clone, which is an expensive operation, so this is by far a better approach.